# CanActivate guard for multiple users in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, auth-guard

I've got a working canActivate auth-guard like this:

```
    return this.auth.user$.map(user => {
      if (user) return true;

      this.router.navigate(["/login"], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
      return false;

    });
  }
```

and use it for routes like this:

```
{path: 'my-project', component: ToolComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

i want to have multiple users be able to work on the same project

example:
User A & B on project 1
User C & B on project 2
and so on

what's the best way to to this?

ty!

Comment: Question needs focus. Research and try out solutions first. Does 'role', 'permission' or 'document' based access fit your criteria (no way for us to know) and look up documentation and tutorials eg. [firestore/solutions/role-based-access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access)

Comment: when you say you want multiple users on the same project, do you mean something like google docs for example, having multiple use edit the same place ? in that case this still should work since each user will load up their own instance on their browser, if you mean something else could you explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "typical" is assing to each user a "role" (admin/user), but in your case I imagine you has severals projects. So your "user" should has a property with the project can access and the path of your router can add "data". Some like

```
  { path: 'project1/ComponentOne', component: Component1,
      canActivate: [CheckGuard],data:{project:"project1"} },
```

Your "checkGuard can take account the "user" and also the "data"

```
@Injectable()
export class CheckGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router,private accountService:AccountService) { }
  canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
     routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    //in activatedRouteSnapshot.data you has the "data" of the router
    console.log(activatedRouteSnapshot.data)

    ...your logic here..
  } 
}
```